# Creating a closure around a private function in elisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, lexical-closures

In elisp I have the following

```
(setq lexical-binding t)



 (fset 'boom (cl-flet*
               ((tickle ()
                        (message "hi"))
                (pickle ()
                        (tickle)))
             (lambda ()
               (pickle))))
(boom)
```

When I run the boom function I get the error

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: --cl-pickle--
```

What's going on here?

My intent is I would like to wrap private/helper functions and variables in a closure so I can better organize my code than everything being global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `(setq lexical-binding t)`.  You don't want to execute a command that sets this variable.  Instead you want to describe to Emacs that the code you write uses lexical binding, and for that you need to add:

```
-*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

somewhere on the first line of the file.

Comment: I'll be damned.  Thanks.